# Show that $\text{rank}(Df)(A) = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ for all $A$ such that $A^TA = I_n$

Tags: linear-algebra, derivatives, matrix-calculus, matrix-rank

> We identify $\mathbb R^{n \times n}$ with $\mathbb R^{n^2}$ and define $f:\mathbb R^{n^2} \to \mathbb R^{n^2}, A \mapsto A^TA$.
>
> Show that $\text{rank}(Df)(A) = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ for all $A$ such that $A^TA = I_n$.

**The solution by Omnomnomnom written in a more accessible (for me) way:**

We firstly note that $$f(A+H)=(A + H)^T(A + H) = A^TA  + H^TA + A^TH +H^TH$$

Consider the following homomorphismus $\Phi:\mathbb R^{n^2} \to \mathbb R^{n^2}, H \mapsto H^TA + A^TH$

Thus the equation above can be written as:

$$f(A+H)= f(A)  + \Phi(H) +H^TH$$

Remember that according to the definition $(Df)(A)$ is a homomorphismus from $\mathbb R^{n^2}$ to $\mathbb R^{n^2}$ such that $$\lim_{H\to 0, H \ne 0} \frac{f(A+H)-f(A)-(Df)(A)H}{\|H\|}=0$$

Because $\lim_{H\to 0, H \ne 0}\|\frac{H^TH}{\|H\|}\| \le \lim_{H\to 0, H \ne 0}\frac{\|H^T\|\|H\|}{\|H\|}=\lim_{H\to 0, H \ne 0}\|H^T\|=0$, it follows that:

$$\lim_{H\to 0, H \ne 0} \frac{f(A+H)-f(A)-\Phi (H)}{\|H\|}=\lim_{H\to 0, H \ne 0} \frac{H^TH}{\|H\|}=0$$ and consequently  $Df(A)=\Phi$.

Now we note that $\{\Phi(H):H \in \mathbb R^{n^2}\}=\{X\in \mathbb R^{n^2} : X^T = X\}$, because:

1) $(H^TA + A^TH)^T = A^TH^{TT} + H^TA^{TT} = H^TA + A^TH$

2) $S$ is symmetric, then $\Phi(\frac{1}{2}AS)=\frac{1}{2}(SA^TA+A^TAS)=S$

Now it follows:
$$\frac{n(n+1)}{2}=\dim \{X\in \mathbb R^{n^2} : X^T = X\}=\dim\{\Phi(H):H \in \mathbb R^{n^2}\}=\text{rank}\Phi=\text{rank}(Df)(A)$$

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by rank $Df = \frac{n(n-1)}{2}$.  Is this the value of $Df$ at a particular choice of $A$?  Certainly, if $A = 0$, then the rank of $Df(A)$ is zero... so what *do* we know about $A$?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom you are right, I have missed an important detail. Now it should be fine.

Comment: The statement is not true (for the reason given by Omnomnomnom). Did you mean $\text{null} (Df(A)) = \frac{n(n-1)}2$?

Comment: You continue to write $n(n-1)/2$ where you **should** be writing $n(n+1)/2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, let's compute the derivative as it is defined [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9chet_derivative#Definition), noting that this coincides with the usual definition except that $Df(A)$, rather than producing an explicit $n^2 \times n^2$ matrix, produces a linear map from $\Bbb R^{n \times n}$ to $\Bbb R^{n \times n}$.

In particular, we compute that
$$
(A + H)^T(A + H) = A^TA  + H^TA + A^TH + o(\|H\|)
$$
So, the map we are considering (at any fixed $A \in \Bbb R^{n \times n}$) is the map $H \mapsto H^TA + A^TH$.

***Explanatory note:*** *This map is a homomorphism from $\mathbb R^{n\times n}$ to $\mathbb R^{n\times n}$ which is representable by the matrix from $\mathbb R^{n^2 \times n^2}$ , rank of which we are trying to find. To go from this version of the derivative to the usual matrix, it suffices to apply the [vectorization operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_(mathematics))*.

Note, however, that the output of this map is always symmetric.  In particular,
$$
(H^TA + A^TH)^T = A^TH^{TT} + H^TA^{TT} = H^TA + A^TH
$$
Thus, the image of this map is necessarily a subset of the space of symmetric matrices, which is a space of dimension $n(n+1)/2$.  Thus, the rank of $Df(A)$ will be **at most** $n(n+1)/2$.

In fact, there is no better upper bound that applies to all $A$.  For example, if we take the derivative at $A = I$, then we find that
$$
[Df(I)](H) = H + H^T
$$
which is *onto* the space of symmetric matrices, and therefore has rank *exactly equal* to $n(n+1)/2$.

---

Proof that $Df(A)$ will have the same rank whenever $A^TA = I$:

We wish to show, in other words, that if $A^TA = I$, then the map $H \mapsto H^TA + A^TH$ is onto. To that effect, it suffices to break this map down into the composition of two maps:
$$
T_1(H) = A^TH\\
T_2(H) = H + H^T
$$
It is clear that $T_1$ is an isomorphism, with inverse $H \mapsto AH$ (recall that $AA^T = A^TA = I$).  We note moreover from our analysis above that $T_2$ is a map with rank $n(n+1)/2$.  It follows that the map
$$
[Df(A)](H) = [T_2 \circ T_1](H)
$$
must also be a linear transformation of rank $n(n+1)/2$, as desired.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom it looks like that you are using that $\lim_{H \to 0, H \ne 0} \frac{H^TH}{\|H\|}=0$ where $\|H\|$ is the regular norm on $\mathbb R^{n^2}$, and $H$ is seen as a vector in $\mathbb R^{n^2}$, why does this equation hold?

Comment: @SergeyZykov it suffices to note that 
$$
\left\|\frac{H^TH}{\|H\|}\right\| = 
\frac{\|H^TH\|}{\|H\|} \leq 
\frac{\|H^T\|\cdot\|H\|}{\|H\|}
$$
In general, it holds that $\|AB\| \leq \|A\| \cdot \|B\|$.

Comment: I've incorporated your suggested edit

Comment: with $\|H\|$ you mean the normal Euclidean norm for $H$ which is seen as an element from $\mathbb R^{n^2}$, don't you? I am asking because there is also a norm for matrices $A \in \mathbb R^{n \times n},\|A\|=\sup\{\|Ax\|: x \in \mathbb R^{n },\|x\| \le 1\}$, so not exactly clear which one you mean.

Comment: I was referring to the normal Euclidean norm (also referred to as the "Frobenius norm" in this context).  However, the same statement applies to either choice of norm (that is, it also applies to the operator norm).

Comment: @SergeyZykov I'm having a hard time finding a quick link.  Anyway, the property can be stated as *"the Frobenius norm is submultiplicative"*.  One source that should have a proof is Horn and Johnson.   In fact, you may have an easier time finding the following two facts: if $\|\cdot\|_2$ denotes the operator norm and $\|\cdot\|_F$ the Frobenius norm, then we have
$$
\|A\|_2 \leq \|A\|_F
\|AB\|_F \leq \|A\|_2 \|B\|_F
$$
of course, with these two facts together, the desired property follows.  You may be able to google these results.  If not, Bhatia's Matrix analysis is another reference.

Comment: @SergeyZykov if you're really having trouble finding a proof of that statement, though, you might want to try posting a question about it.

Comment: There is a nice proof on [German wiki](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobeniusnorm#Submultiplikativit.C3.A4t)

Answer (score 0):

A geometrical proof. It suffices to prove that, if $A\in O(n)$, then $dim\ker(Df_A)=n(n-1)/2$. Note that $Df_A(H)=0$ iff $H^TA+A^TH=0$ (Serguey, learn to differentiate a product...), that is, $H$ is in the tangent space $T_A$ to $O(n)$ in $A$. Thus $\ker(Df_A)=T_A$ (it is because $O(n)$ is a level curve of $f$). Since $O(n)$ is a group, $T_A\sim T_I$, the set of skew-symmetric matrices -which is a vector space of dimension $n(n-1)/2$-; and we are done...

EDIT. We can generalize this result; in fact, $O(n)$ has nothing to do here.

Proposition. Let $A\in GL_n(\mathbb{R})$; then $rank(Df_A)=n(n+1)/2$, that is, the function $A\in GL_n(\mathbb{R})\rightarrow A^TA\in S_n^{++}$ is a submersion in each invertible matrix.

Proof. As above, $H\in \ker(Df_A)$ iff $A^TH\in SK_n$, the set of skew-symmetric matrices. Then $\ker(Df_A)=A^{-T}(SK_n)$, a vector space of dimension $n(n-1)/2$ and we are done.